# Copied-and-pasted tab characters not recognized by Powershell

Tags: powershell

Powershell ignores tab characters in copied-and-pasted code snippets. This is annoying because I like to write my Python code with single tabs instead of quadruple spaces, and in testing I frequently copy and paste snippets in to test them.

So far I've been using other terminals like Cygwin that properly address pasted tabs, but it would be more convenient for me to use Powershell. How can it be made to address these pasted tabs correctly?

The MWE is to copy and paste anything with a tab into Powershell. For example,
   `test`
appears in Powershell as
`>>> test`
with no indentation. I've copied and pasted from both Notepad and Notepad++ with the same effect; I'm not using any formatted word processors or anything like that.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. How about a [mre]? Or you have to elaborate a little more detailed. Most PowerShell coders use either ISE or VSCode for developing. In VSCOde you can configure to use either tabs or 4 spaces instead of tabs

Comment: I've added that - really, all there is to it is copying any line with a tab into Powershell. Copying and pasting ` a` is a MWE as the tab character will not be present in the command line. I would be glad to give you more information, but if I had any other ideas what to check, I would have done so before posting here.

Comment: Tab characters do not have any syntactical meaning in PowerShell. They just get ignored. AFAIK there is no setting you could do to change that. Use spaces instead. AFAIK Python is able to use spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: Try clicking the icon in the PowerShell console. Select `Properties` --> `Options` and toggle the 'Filter clipboard contents on paste'. Perhaps that is what you encounter?

Comment: @Theo That does not change this behaviour for me. Do you get tabs when you paste them to a PowerShell console?

Comment: @Olaf I get tabs when i hit Ctrl-V. If I rightclick, then no tabs..

Comment: Ah ... ok, that's the same for me as well.

Comment: I'd recommend updating your question to explicitly mention that this happens "while running the Python CLI". As this is not an issue with PowerShell directly, it's an issue with running Python in a PowerShell terminal. It took me a minute to understand what you were saying and I'm going to guess that's why this is getting downvoted and other confusion.

Answer (score 4):

**Caveat**: The *next section* only applies to *PowerShell's own* interactive prompt. Different rules may apply to external programs *launched from* PowerShell that present their own interactive prompt, such as `python` and, preferably, `ipython` - see the *bottom section* for considerations specific to these programs.

---

##### Preserving tabs on pasting *directly into PowerShell's interactive prompt*:

Note: Strictly speaking, when it does work, **tabs are converted to *4 spaces* each on pasting**.

**Only works when *all* of the following prerequisites are met**:

- When running ***PowerShell (Core) 7+*** (as opposed to *Windows PowerShell*)
- When **pasting via <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>** rather than via right-click (the latter *emulates typing* and therefore triggers tab completion).
- When running in **one of the following console environments**:

  - Regular console window (`conhost.exe`)
  - Windows Terminal
  - Note:

    - Does *not* work in Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal (which seemingly always *emulates typing* in PowerShell).
    - Haven't tried third-party consoles such as Cygwin and ConEmu.

Notably, this **categorically excludes *Windows PowerShell*** (where a tab ends up as `^I`).

---

##### Preserving tabs on pasting into the interactive `python` / `ipython` REPL, from PowerShell or `cmd.exe`:

Note:

- `ipython` provides a superior REPL experience compared to `python`.
- Unlike the above, the following also applies to launching from *Windows PowerShell*, as well as from `cmd.exe`.
- When it works, pasted tabs are converted to *4 spaces*, except where noted otherwise.

**`ipython`**

- Regular console windows (`conhost.exe`):

  - Works, with <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> only.
- [Windows Terminal](https://aka.ms/windowsterminal):

  - Works, with <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> only.
- [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com)'s integrated terminal:

  - Does NOT work (strips tabs).

**`python`**

- Regular console windows (`conhost.exe`):

  - Works, with both <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> and right-click, *as long as `Filter clipboard contents on paste` is turned OFF* on the `Options` tab of the console window's `Properties` dialog; pastes *actual tabs*.
- Windows Terminal:

  - Works, with right-click only(!); pastes *actual tabs*.
- Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal:

  - Works.

Comment: "Filter clipboard contents on paste is turned OFF" -- brilliant!  I groped around for an hour till I found this tidbit.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to make this work was by using Windows Terminal. Which is a new terminal application built by Microsoft that supports a bunch of new features.

I don't know the technical reasons why, but it appears it supports pasting both tabs and spaces appropriately, without loss or conversion into the Python CLI REPL.

I tested this using Windows Terminal while running Windows PowerShell, PowerShell Core 7+ and Command Prompt, while running the Python CLI and all supported pasting tabs.

You can install Windows Terminal through a number of sources...Windows Store, Binary download, WinGet, Choco, etc.

Here's the github repo with instructions on various ways to install.

https://github.com/microsoft/terminal

Answer (score 0):

In general, control-v is better for pasting characters than right-click.  Note control-v has to be bound to psreadline's paste function (so no emacs mode).  Here's an example with an a and an em dash (0x2013).  Right click will only paste the a.

```
a–
```