# Do not convert tabs to spaces when printing in CPython console

Tags: python, powershell, printing, tabs, console

##### Problem

The statement

```py
print(".\t.")
```

returns the string `.       .` in the CPython console (the tab is replaced by 7 spaces). How can I preserve the tab character?

Copying all output from the console to notepad++ shows the following output (whitespaces made visible):
[image: notepad++ including white spaces]

The problem may be related to the underlying console software rather than python (see "My research" below)

##### Setup

I am using Anaconda 3.9 on Windows 10 Enterprise.

The problem occurs when

- I run Python from the command prompt cmd
- I run Python from the powershell
- I run IPython from the powershell
- I run a Python script from VSCode (I guess it is using the Powershell)
- I run a Python 2 interpreter not managed by Anaconda

(The list above contains only the tested cases. I have not found an example where it works.)

##### Use case

I want to print a tab-separated list that can be copied and pasted to tables in other software (such as Excel) that distributes tab-separated lists to individual cells.

##### My research

The problem seems to go a little deeper than Python. Potentially, the default consoles on Windows (cmd and Powershell) cannot display tab characters. Some threads suggest this:

- [How do I echo a TAB char on a command prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/240435/how-do-i-echo-a-tab-char-on-a-command-prompt)
- [Copied-and-pasted tab characters not recognized by Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70144322/copied-and-pasted-tab-characters-not-recognized-by-powershell)

In the provided answers, tabs only work converted to spaces. I wonder if the problem could be circumvented by using a different console / UI.

I have also found several similar questions related to specific IDEs or consoles (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980943/how-to-prevent-tab-characters-from-being-converted-to-spaces-in-console-output-w) or [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/10890)). However, the issue remained either unresolved or the solutions applied only to the specific software.

Comment: that *is* preserving the tab character. It doesn't get converted to spaces in my console at least

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Are you able to copy the string and paste it in an editor, say, notepad++ and not end up with spaces?

Comment: Now, you could print the `repr` of the string, which will provide a string that is a valid string literal iteslf, such that if you `eval`ed it, it would evaluate to the same string, but that won't necessarily be consumabble by any other arbitrary program

Comment: yes, e.g. VSCode and PyCharm, and the terminal itself

Comment: are you sure whatever editor you are using isn't doing this conversion due to some setting? How exactly are you running this? The behavior you are describing is not one I've seen in either Linux or Mac, haven't really tested it out in Windows, but I would honestly be surprised if that were the case.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have added information regarding the setup. Yes, the consumability by the other program is exactly the issue. It is not difficult to print a sting with `\t` otherwise. (I could simply do `print(".\\t".)` or `print(r".\t".)`)

Comment: I mean, again, in my iTerm terminal emulator, what gets printed to the screen is a tab, not many spaces (even though it is a whitespace character, not an escape sequence). This is always the behavior I've encountered and the behavior I would expect.

Comment: Yes, this is the behaviour I would expect as well. So the question is then what could be different / wrong with my setup or configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of data structure you want to print.
If you have tabular structure I would generally recommend using `pandas` to work with your data.

With `pandas` you can create a `DataFrame` and if you want to create a
`tsv` file you can do that with [`DataFrame.to_csv(sep='\t')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

If you want to pretty print tabular structure you can use [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) library, which could be useful in your case.
Be aware that this is not an answer to your initial question,
but rather a recommendation to create such an output.

Else I can only say that printing `\t` can yield different results based on the console you're using because it's not always directly converted to 4 spaces.

Comment: My goal is indeed to have the tab directly in the console (for convenience reasons). "`\t` can yield different results based on the console you're using" -> Which console would keep the `\t`?